# Use data from getJSON to populate tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I'm correct `getJSON` cannot return the words as it is an asynchronous method.
How can I improve the following piece of code to populate the title with the variable called `words` that contains the data I want to push in the tooltip `title` attribute?

```
$('.multiselect-container li').not('.filter, .group').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: function () {
        var req = $.getJSON('localfile.json', function(data) {
            var words = data["blarg"]["something"];
        });
        return "content"; // words variable should fit here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the tooltip creation inside the ajax callback function

```
$.getJSON('localfile.json', function(data) {
  var words = data["blarg"]["something"];
  $('.multiselect-container li').not('.filter, .group').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: function () {
      return words; // words variable should fit here
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the solutions is to call an ajax function synchronously. here's an example

```
function getData()
{
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            else
                AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (AJAX)
            {
                AJAX.open("GET", "localfile.json", false);
                AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                AJAX.send();
                return JSON.parse(AJAX.responseText);                                         
            } 
            else
                return null;
}
```

Then all you need to do in your code is this :

```
$('.multiselect-container li').not('.filter, .group').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: getData
});
```

Comment: If you want to make the user wait while the tooltips are requested, sure... ;)

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest requests should be avoided if at all possible, since they block the UI while waiting for a response (and it is possible to avoid it here, so I would recommend @PitaJ's answer.) Also, if you're going to do it synchronously, you could just use jQuery's `async: false` option.

Comment: @CaseyFalk, I like making the user wait :)